How generate cHash to use for URL for an href in an <a> in own ViewHelper
I have to create a  tag in a ViewHelper in my own extension, but I don't know how to do it, that it works with Typo3. It has to use for an anchor  element, but this anchor  is only a small part of the ViewHelper. This is the URL:
/sonstiges/test?tx_review_listreviews[action]=list&tx_review_listreviews[controller]=Reviews
For which part I have to create the cHash?
And how can I create the cHash inside the Viewhelper?
clyssCan I use md5?
Is there any function which I use inside the ViewHelper class?
A example would be great!

Could you elaborate more what your viewhelper should do? Why is <f:link...> not suitable for you? Also, instead of a viewhelper you might use the linkbuildwe facilities in your controller to prepare your variables. Better to have logic in your Controller than putting logic into ViewHelpers.

In the view it generates a complete page (Text, picture und data) out of a database value and one part is a link back to the list way.

Finally I found a solution in Typo3, which I included into my viewHelper:
`<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyExtension\MyClass;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ExtbaseRequestParameters;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder;

final class MyClass
{
public function __construct(
    private readonly UriBuilder $uriBuilder,
) {}

public function doSomething()
{
    $this->uriBuilder->setRequest($this->getExtbaseRequest());

    $url = $this->uriBuilder
        ->reset()
        ->setTargetPageUid(42)
        ->uriFor(
            'myAction',
            [
                'myRecord' => 21,
            ],
            'MyController',
            'myextension',
            'myplugin',
        );

    // do something with $url
}

private function getExtbaseRequest(): RequestInterface
{
    /** @var ServerRequestInterface $request */
    $request = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'];

    // We have to provide an Extbase request object
    return new Request(
        $request->withAttribute('extbase', new ExtbaseRequestParameters()),
    );
}

}
`
